# Unjustified and undetected circular type definition when using one-tuple to prevent distributive conditional type with a condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Code example**

```
type Test<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? { array: Test<T[0]> } : { notArray: T };
declare const x: Test<number[]>;
const y: { array: { notArray: number } } = x; // Error
declare const a: Test<number>;
const b: { notArray: number } = a; // Works
```

Line 3 fail with the following error:

```
Type '{ array: { array: { array: ...; }; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ array: { notArray: number; }; }'.
```

i.e. the type Test<number[]> resolves to an infinitive recursive loop.

**Expected Result**

I Expect this to to compile without error:
`T = number[]`, i.e. the condition is true
`Test<T[0]>` = `Test<number[][0]>` = `Test<number>` = `{ notArray: number }`

And indeed, as you can see from the last line - `Test<number>` resolves to `{notArray: number}`.

When removing the one-tuple from the condition:
`type Test<T> = T extends any[] ? { array: Test<T[0]> } : { notArray: T };` there is no issue, but unfortunately, that leads to a different problem:

`Test<boolean>` is resolved to `{ notArray: true} | { notArray: false}` (because of distributive conditional types) instead of `{ notArray: boolean }`, which can be problematic in certain situations, which applies to my usecase. According to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37279, using the one-tuple in the condition should solve this issue.

**Question**

Is this a bug in TypeScript? Is there a way / a workaround to accomplish what I want while preventing distributive conditional types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrapping the array type using `T[0]` is not working.

The generic will be called like `Test<number[][0]>` which results in this weird recursive type error.

Instead you want to unwrap the array and pass it on. Therefore you can use a simple helper type to unwrap the array:

```js
type UnwrapArray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;
type Test<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? { array: Test<UnwrapArray<T>> } : { notArray: T };

// -- Your mentioned use cases --
declare const x: Test<number[]>;
const y: { array: { notArray: number } } = x;

declare const a: Test<number>;
const b: { notArray: number } = a;


declare const z: Test<boolean>;
const yy: { notArray: boolean } = z;
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!
Thanks for the help. It worked perfectly.